# context redirection on an expression parser's execution

Tags: algorithm, parsing, compiler-construction

in my business engine (that I use to make screens, forms, etc...) I have a small script language that is in the form of "parameter = value", to give it more flexibility, the value part is a standar mathematical expression that can use internal engine variables and functions.
nowadays I use a standar method of parsing it by changing the string to tokens, then do a sintactical analisis then use a shunting algorythm to convert it to postfix notation so while in the engine runtime I can use the current value of the expression instead of constant values.
The problem comes here, there is such a thing as expression context, let's say an expression is run on graph1 so the maxValue variable or the _average("row1") function depend on that graph , but a necesity surfaced that I need to get data from other ocntext, let's say graph2 in the graph1 expression; something like, in graph1 code:
color = maxValue > graph2->maxValue
so the color of graph1 changes depending on whether or not graph2's maxvalue is smaller than graph1's.
as it's implied there, I partially solved it by using the -> operator, the left part of the operator is a context reference so when this operator is being used I change the context to the left parameter's then return the value of the right parameter but this being an expresion parser, once it gets to the operator, the values have been previously calculated, so max value already returns the maxvalue of graph1's, the partial solution passes the left and right variable names to the operator, so I can just "re-get" the value of the variable with the new context, but that still leaves functions unsolved.
My question is if my aproach of using redirection as a binary operator is the best method, as a start, or if there are other aproaches I could use in the evaluation ofthe shunting algorythm result to get the proper function values.

Answer (score 1):

coding the redirection expression a an unary, postfix operator fixed the problem in the simplest way